# Changing embedded Tomcat server port to 80 in Springboot web in gradle environment is Error, when 80 port hasn't use.Why?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, port80

These days,I have working a springboot web program ,then I want to change server port to 80 ,but it always error. I have found some measure,but generally method has not work ,I hope some people can help me solve it.Thank you very much !

I use embeded Tomcat server ,Error Info is below:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-25 19:31:58.325  INFO 3890 --- [           main] top.uniondong.home.HomeApplication       : Starting HomeApplication on dong-manjaro with PID 3890 (/home/dong/Program/Uniondong_Home/build/classes/java/main started by dong in /home/dong/Program/Uniondong_Home)
2020-03-25 19:31:58.330  INFO 3890 --- [           main] top.uniondong.home.HomeApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-25 19:32:00.031  INFO 3890 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
2020-03-25 19:32:00.044  INFO 3890 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-25 19:32:00.045  INFO 3890 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-03-25 19:32:00.160  INFO 3890 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-25 19:32:00.160  INFO 3890 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1686 ms
2020-03-25 19:32:00.470  INFO 3890 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-25 19:32:00.531  INFO 3890 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2020-03-25 19:32:00.690  INFO 3890 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-03-25 19:32:00.697  INFO 3890 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-25 19:32:00.709 ERROR 3890 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at top.uniondong.home.HomeApplication.main(HomeApplication.java:12) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:278) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1038) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: 权限不够
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:220) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:229) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1035) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

2020-03-25 19:32:00.712  INFO 3890 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: All ports up to 1024 are reserved for the root user.

Comment: Oh, I am understand . Are there any solutions？

Comment: I have found some solutions ,I am tring , Thank you very much !